# getting invalid hook in useNavigate react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm getting invalid hook error on useNavigate hook:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import styles from "./Home.module.css";
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import Card from "../../components/shared/Card/Card";
    import Button from "../../components/shared/Button/Button";
    
    const Home = () => {
      const signInLinkStyle = {
        color: '#0077ff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        marginLeft: '10px'
      }
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      
      const startRegister = () => {
        navigate("/authenticate");
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className={styles.cardWrapper}>
            <Card title='Welcome to Codershouse!' icon='logo'>
            <p className={styles.text}>
                We’re working hard to get Codershouse ready for everyone! While we
                wrap up the finishing youches, we’re adding people gradually to make
                sure nothing breaks :)
            </p>
              <div>
                <Button onClick={ startRegister } text="Let's Go"/>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.signinWrapper}>
              <span className={styles.hasInvite}>Have an invite text?</span>
              </div>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

Package.json

```json
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Full error image:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `package.json` in a code block? And edit you post to add code blocks? Thanks!

Comment: yes sir I have edit the code block

Comment: And what is the version of `react-router-dom` that you are using?

Comment: it is "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1" but now it is start working thank you 